# Does $\|\cdot\|$ in a general Banach $\ast$ Algebra preserve order?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Given a general Banach $\ast$-Algebra $\mathcal{B}$ and $a, b \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $a > b > 0$ (i.e. we have $a^* = a, b^* = b, (a - b)^* = a - b$ and $\sigma(a), \sigma(b), \sigma(a - b) \subseteq [0, \infty)$), is it always true that $\|a\| > \|b\|$? Does $a > b$ necessarily implies $\sigma(b) \subsetneq \sigma(a)$

In $C^*$ Algebra since the Gelfand mapping $\Gamma$ is isometry, given $a > b > 0$ we can tell $\|a\| > \|b\|$. However in a general Banach $\ast$-Algebra I do not know if this is true.

Comment: Trivial counterexample, as we see in the Answer below: In $C(K)$, if $f=-2$ and $g=-1$ then $f<g$ but $||f||>||g||$.

Comment: Of course in $C(K)$, hence in any C* algebra, if $0\le f\le g$ then $||f||\le||g||$. Maybe you should ask whether $0\le a\le b$ implies $||a||\le||b||$? (I tend to doubt that's true in a general Banach algebra, but we haven't seen a counterexample yet...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for reminding me. I did forget to add "both $a$ and $b$ are positive" ….. and the question with this line is what I actually want to ask.

Comment: Your definition of positivity is very different from the usual definition. $\sigma(x)\subset (0,\infty)$ is _not_ enough for positivity, usually you also ask $x=x^*$, where $*$ is an involution of the algebra. So you should be looking at a Banach $*$-algebra. Else consider $b=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1000\\ 0 &1\end{pmatrix}, a = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ for a counter-example.

Comment: @s.harp This is a nice counter-example. Meanwhile in references I have positive element always appear after the definition of $C^*$ Algebra. Before your comment I believe positive element in Banach Algebra could be defined in this way but now I need to double check. To make the definition more rigorous I will edit the question soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal B$ be the Banach algebra $C^1_b([0,1])$ of real-valued continuously differentiable functions from $[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ with pointwise multiplication and the standard $C^1$-norm. With identity as trivial involution it is a Banach $*$-algebra.

Define $a(x):=4$, $b_n(x):=\sin(n\pi x)+2$. Then $a>b_n>0$ for all $n$. But $\|b_n\|\to\infty$ for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is nice and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $C[0,1]$. Here $\sigma (a-b) \subseteq [0,\infty)$ iff $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x$. But $\|f\| \geq \|g\|$ neither implies nor is  implied by this.

Comment: I am sorry to tell you I forget to add that "$a > b > 0$". Given the counterexample from David, without this line this question will be quite trivial.